# MinGW setup for "network" package

Tags: haskell, mingw

During cabal install `network` I'm getting:

> `__printf__` not found in DLL .. 
>   .... \mingw32\bin\as.exe

and it fails.

What did I forgot to install? 
What `MinGW` setup should I have?

Comment: This question is about tools involved in Haskell development, so I disagree with the outstanding close vote that it belongs on superuser.

Comment: You don't need to use a separate mingw install, your ghc is supposed to come with everything you need, except bash. You can take bash from msys (comes with mingw usually) or cygwin. I've just cabal-installed `network` with a an x86-64 ghc and bash from msys.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a working Windows development environment that allows you to update network has always been something of a pain. I know other people have had success setting up a MSYS2 environment and compiling network using that. These are my notes from the last time I set one up (this was prior to MSYS2): http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/01/setting-up-haskell-development.html

Comment: Thanks but it's not very clear. I mean maybe by luck someone can answer with exact thing that I miss...